# Force explicit mapping for all target fields with Mapstruct

Tags: java, mapstruct

Let's say I have the following objects

```
public class ClassA {
  private String fieldA;
  private String fieldB;
}

public class ClassB {
  private String fieldA;
  private String fieldBWithDifferentName;
  private String fieldC;
}
```

I want to force explicit mappings for all fields in ClassB and force a compile error when a field is not mapped.

I know I can use `@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.ERROR)` for fieldC to force `@Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)` so my mapper would look like this

```
@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.ERROR)
public interface Mapper {

  @Mapping(target = "fieldBWithDifferentName", source = "fieldB")
  @Mapping(target = "fieldC", ignore = true)
  ClassB toClassB(final ClassA classA);
}
```

However, this mapper will automatically map fieldA, because it exists in both classes. And even though I do want to map fieldA, I want the developer to have to do it explicitly and have mapstruct throw an error if it has to resort to the automatic mapping functionality.

Basically, I want to force a `@Mapping` for every field in the target. Is this possible?

Comment: There's an issue for this on the mapstruct github https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/2889

Answer (score 0):

Disabling implicit mapping is possible via `@BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true)` but this annotation must be set on each method. Look at the MapStruct reference guide in § 3.1. Basic mappings :

> By means of the @BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true) the default
> behavior will be explicit mapping, meaning that all mappings have to
> be specified by means of the @Mapping and no warnings will be issued
> on missing target properties. This allows to ignore all fields, except
> the ones that are explicitly defined through @Mapping.

Comment: you could also look at this same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34629563